# Java: Is it bad practice to have same package name in the different libraries?

Tags: java, class, oop, package

Let's say I have 2 own libraries with the following classes:

lib1:

```
name.of.the.package.A
```

lib2:

```
name.of.the.package.B
```

The package name is the same, but class names are different. So, I can use both of these classes in the same place without any compilation or runtime exceptions. Moreover, I check that it's possible to import both classes using star:

```
import name.of.the.package.*;

...


A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

I think it's a bad approach because if these packages contain classes with the same name usage of them became painfull. What do you say?

Comment: This is known as a "split package" and is no longer possible under the Java module system added in Java 9 (though can still be used if not using modules).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bad practice. If you have package private classes or class members in one library, you expect that no other classes will access them and that they work as expected. But classes from the same package can break this.